# scrolling in listview with different cell height

Tags: android, listview, scroll, height

I have a listview and its rows have different heights.

When I scroll up, rows appear to move up or down erratically.
(I don't find the behavior when I scroll down)

I suspect its due to the fact

> 1. listView picks one of used rows
> 2. the row is placed on top of visible rows.
> 3. listView changes the row's height(here erratic movement)

but it's a guess.

I tried googling since this should be a common problem but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, setting the right item height did the trick :

[How to set different heights for each row in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512592/how-to-set-different-heights-for-each-row-in-a-listview)

Edit: oh, and make sure you recycle the items correctly :

[ListView reusing views when ... I don't want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to)

Comment: general idea is correct, I set imageHeight in getView with `imageView.getLayoutParams().height = aHeight;`