# How can I make my ListView items always wrap their content height wise

Tags: android

Right now if there is a list item that is 2 lines in height then all the rows are two lines in height

How can I make the rows' height independent on other rows.

**ListView**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/user_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Row**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrolling in listview with different cell height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036810/scrolling-in-listview-with-different-cell-height)

Comment: Is the container for the row xml files set to `wrap_content` too?

Comment: Are you using a custom Adapter? The XML you posted should be working at a quick glance, however you may be inflating the views incorrectly which makes the "wrap_content" attribute ignored. If you're using a custom adapter, please post the code for it, else just post the Java code you're using to show your list.