# Android ListView with items containing images of different heights

Tags: android, listview, smooth-scrolling

I have a ListView with items containing one ImageView which height can vary depending on data. When I scroll up  the list is shaking because of convertView and result view have different heights.

When I scroll down scrolling is smooth, can I somehow fix heights for upper items?

Comment: pls post your xml & adapter code

Comment: but still post it as without knowing what you doing its not possible for us to help you.

Comment: fix height of `ImageView`(E.g. 50dp) in listitem.xml

Comment: Using items of different size with ListView is a bad idea. ListView measures it's children based on first one.

Comment: Alexey, can you advise some scrollable container to be used for different items?

Comment: No code == No solution.

Comment: @Ketan, of course fixing image height solves the problem, I want to have different heights

Comment: @GrIsHu No code == No solution isn't always equals to true :) My code is really complex, about 1000 lines of code... But the problem is very popular. The same as one image in listview item

Comment: @GrIsHu I'll give you 200 of my reputation if you google it for me

Comment: @elf_zwölf: if this is popular, please give community some references

Comment: @xjaphx: for example this (problem there isn't solved despite the answer is accepted) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036810/scrolling-in-listview-with-different-cell-height

Comment: @elf_zwölf: Did you find the solution? I'm facing a same problem...

Comment: @SabaJamalian solution was to create many different item view types for different heights of images.