# How can I make my listview rows different heights

Tags: java, android, listview

Right now if there is a list item that is 2 lines in height then all the rows are two lines in height

How can I make the rows' height independent on other rows.

**ListView**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/user_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Row**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am using a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter. the getView there is nothing special, just a viewholder patern I don't change height or anything

Comment: Could you post some images of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @sriramramani Ahmed Ekri's answer has an image of what I want to achieve as far as the height wrapping

Comment: @codefish578841441 if u want to create list view in which each row height is independent of each other then u need to create ur own list-view(i.e put inflated views in scroll view and handle click events on each of the raw..)..by doing this u can create raw of any height depends on ur no of text lines.

Comment: @codefish578841441: kindly post your customadapter code

Answer (score 10):

why don't you try making the height = 0dp and weight 1

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**update:**

check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7513423/1932105

[image]

Comment: This made the rows invisible

Comment: Thanks for the update. the height is already set to wrap_contents but it doesn't work

Comment: try removing the         android:layout_weight="0"

Comment: Nope that didn't work either, they invisible but still clickable. i even get a lint error saying they will be invisible

Comment: Try setting the LinearLayout's orientation to vertical, should help with the invisibility issue. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are restricting it the `TextView` to have a maximum of 2 lines. It will never grow more than that. Remove `android:maxLines="2"`. It should work automatically.

Answer (score 3):

> The trick for me was not setting the height -- but instead setting the
>   minHeight. This must be applied to the root view of whatever layout
>   your custom adapter is using to render each row.

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368439/2498729

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

> seemed no effect.

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

> changed the height for me

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4274505/2498729

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you'll have to make visibility of your text views to be `View.GONE` when they are empty. You can do it in adapter implementation.

```
pointsView.setText(pointsText);
pointsView.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(pointsText) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

But be careful since your views are in `RelativeLayout` and its rules can stop working when an anchored view gets visibility `View.GONE`.

In such case you may try setting text size to zero instead of changing the view visibility, but I haven't tried it myself.

```
pointsView.setTextSize(TextUtils.isEmpty(pointsText) ? 0 : defaultSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited with the TextView MaxLine then please remove `android:maxLines="2"` this will automatically adjust the height of list.

 If you are looking for increasing the height of one particular row independent of others. After setting the adapter value for the list. Get the list 
`final ListView lv = getListView();`
then form the `lv` get the particular row  by 
`lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position)` or any similar logic that best suited in your code. and change the row appearance programmatically as you looking for. Thanks.